# Oracle Apex: radio buttons, forms and reports

Tags: forms, report, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, interactive

Is it possible to create a radio button field or a checkbox field for each row of an interactive report?

If the above is possible, submit that selected row which would take the user to another report combining different tables?

Please explain how this is possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create items using [apex_item](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) if you want to create a check box you will need to use:

```
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2( p_idx                       IN    NUMBER
                   , p_value                     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                   , p_attributes                IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                   , p_checked_values            IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                   , p_checked_values_delimiter  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ':'
                   , p_item_id                   IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                   , p_item_label                IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
 RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

as you can see multiple examples in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI193) if you want an IR with a custom checkbox you can do it this way:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,empno) "Select"
,      ename
,      job
FROM   emp
ORDER  by 1
```

If I understand correctly after the user select any number of check boxes he can click on a button to show another report where you will need the selected check boxes. One way to achieve this is:

1. Create a process to add the selected check boxes to a collection

   ```
   BEGIN
       apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name => 'col_tmp');

       FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT
       LOOP  
           apex_collection.add_member( p_collection_name => 'col_tmp'
                                 , p_c001            => APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i));                
       END LOOP;
   END;
   ```
2. Create a branch to the page with the other report. In this page you can use the collection in your select in order to show the right information:

   ```
   SELECT e.ename
   ,      e.job
   ,      d.dname
     FROM EMP e,
          DEPT d
    WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
      AND empno IN (SELECT C001
                      FROM apex_collections
                     WHERE collection_name = 'COL_TMP')
   ```

NOTE: In the select you must use the collection name in upper case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm quite new to Apex and was wondering if you have come across any working demo's that I could see how it works together after executing the above steps?

Comment: [Here you go](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login_page?p_flow_page=25904:55:)

This is actually the apex sample application and you just need to enter a username to login. (This link will only be available for a few days).

Comment: Thank you so much for the link but sadly it doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyway :) I'll try searching for a demo

Comment: Thank you so much. This works  and its exactly what I want my application to do. Thanks again for your help. Is it alright to comment here if I hit a road block when I implement this feature?

Comment: If it's related to this question you can ask here otherwise is better to create another question to get more visibility.